# How can I extract the Speaker annotation from a conversation?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, speaker

When using Stanford CoreNLP, I get results in an xml output file. Inside it I find a column with the name of the speaker for example:

```
        <word>Mike</word>
        <lemma>Mike</lemma>
        <CharacterOffsetBegin>0</CharacterOffsetBegin>
        <CharacterOffsetEnd>4</CharacterOffsetEnd>
        <POS>NNP</POS>
        <NER>PERSON</NER>

        *<Speaker>PER0</Speaker>*

        <TrueCase>INIT_UPPER</TrueCase>
        <TrueCaseText>Mike</TrueCaseText>
        <sentiment>Neutral</sentiment>
```

So how can i manipulate Speaker results in java code ? And how can i improve it's results ? For example in a conversation I'd like to get Mike instead of PER0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use DOM XML parser:

[How to read an XML File with the Java DOM Parser](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: Yes, but i need also to improve the generated results.
I think there is a Speaker Annotator that I should be able to manipulate.

Comment: Is this XML snippet deep down in the DOM tree ? So this is repeated for multiple Speakers? You could search for the root element which contains the Speaker as a child, then return the word element which is Mike.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you @Thomas Bigger for your answers
I will try to be more clear, 
In this code,

```
    PrintWriter xmlOut = new PrintWriter("xmlOutput.xml");   
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, truecase, ner, parse,quote, mention, dcoref, sentiment"); 
    props.put("truecase.overwriteText", "true");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);       
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("Mike said : \"I vote for Hillary.\"\n 
                                           peter said : \"I vote for Donald.\"");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);   
    pipeline.xmlPrint(annotation, xmlOut);
```

The xmlOut.xml present the analysis of two sentences:

[First Sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfzty.png)

< Mike said > , < : > , < " > and < " > are considered as the narator's speech(PER0). 
< I vote for Hillary > is considered as a speech of person 1.

[Second Sentence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPVDS.png)

< Peter said > , < : > , < " > and < " > are considered as the narator's speech(PER0). 
< I vote for Donald. > is considered as Peter's speech. => The only difference here is that i wrote peter with lowercase and when I write it with uppercase the result of speaker become 4.

While searching in JavaDoc on Stanford CoreNLP I find classes talking about Speaker such : 
- CoreAnnotations.SpeakerAnnotation 
- CoreNLPProtos.SpeakerInfo
- CoreNLPProtos.SpeakerInfo.Builder
- CoreNLPProtos.SpeakerInfoOrBuilder
- SpeakerInfo
- SpeakerInfo
- SpeakerMatch

So I'd like first, to have more efficient results into my xmlOut and second, to know how can i use these classes to extract speakers and their speech without using DOM XML.